# Version settings issue - It reverts back to a particular settings

Tags: versioning

SP 2010: Library Version Settings:

I changed version settings to 
 - Create major and minor (draft) versions from 
   Keep the following number of major versions: checked (6)
   Keep drafts for the following number of major versions: (5)

To

Keep the following number of major versions: unchecked and no numbers in the box
Keep drafts for the following number of major versions: (5)

After few hours my changes are reverted back to original settings. Any idea how to fix this issue? I am suspecting the libraries were created using a stp of existing library and version settings are hard coded and reverting back. May be I am wrong.

Either case how do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got the XML from the SP Designer. The first is original settings and 2nd is what I changed so there are no limit for Major version (unlimited). (The original post is not editable so I am adding)

```
<List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{1E98F2E1-45D7-4C0C-BCF8-65604B076226}" Title="Customers" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" Name="{1E98F2E1-45D7-4C0C-BCF8-65604B076226}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="{00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101}" ServerTemplate="101" Created="20140522 05:04:25" Modified="20161213 15:14:02" LastDeleted="20161201 15:17:13" Version="260" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="0" WebImageWidth="0" WebImageHeight="0" Flags="618402952" ItemCount="69" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="/mgmt/orders/Customers" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="18" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/mgmt/orders" WebId="8e1f176b-80d2-4104-8336-9a9980c1269a" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="af04b54b-c063-4ab1-927b-fc165e4e2b7d" MajorVersionLimit="6" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="5" WorkFlowId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="False" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="True" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="True" RequireCheckout="True" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="25000">



<List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{1E98F2E1-45D7-4C0C-BCF8-65604B076226}" Title="Customers" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itdl.png" Name="{1E98F2E1-45D7-4C0C-BCF8-65604B076226}" BaseType="1" FeatureId="{00BFEA71-E717-4E80-AA17-D0C71B360101}" ServerTemplate="101" Created="20140522 05:04:25" Modified="20161213 17:27:40" LastDeleted="20161201 15:17:13" Version="261" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="0" WebImageWidth="0" WebImageHeight="0" Flags="618402952" ItemCount="69" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="/mgmt/orders/Customers" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="18" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/mgmt/orders" WebId="8e1f176b-80d2-4104-8336-9a9980c1269a" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="af04b54b-c063-4ab1-927b-fc165e4e2b7d" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="5" WorkFlowId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="False" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="False" EnableModeration="True" EnableVersioning="True" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="True" RequireCheckout="True" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="25000">
```